# Monte carlo simulation - probability if two integers are coprime?

Tags: java, montecarlo

Im trying to write a Java program that uses a Monte Carlo simulation to calculate the probability that two randomly selected numbers are coprime. Two integers are coprime if the only positive integer that divides evenly into both is 1. I tried to use Euclid's algorithm to find the GCD and if that's equal to 1, find the probability of how many times it's equal to 1. It didnt execute, any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonteCarlo
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    int b = scan.nextInt();

public static int euclidMethod(int a, int b) //euclid's algorithm
{
    if(b==0)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return euclidMethod(b, a % b);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        if(euclidMethod() == 1)
        {
            return (euclidMethod() / 100); //probability its equal to 1
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. Your `euclidMethod` requires two arguments, and you're trying to call it with none. Also you're setting `a` and `b` once, so your simulation would just be testing the same "random" numbers millions of times. Perhaps you should start with something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to execute this code, you will have this error:

> [...]: method euclidMethod in class MonteCarlo
> cannot be applied to given types;
>
> *if(euclidMethod() == 1)*
>
> **required**: int,int
>
> **found**: no arguments
>
> [...]

Now, what it means? `euclidMethod` **requires** two arguments of type int, but *no arguments* have been **found**.

You have to call:

```
euclidMethod(a, b);
```

or something like this whenever you want to use the method.
If you want to call `euclidMethod();` you've to write a new method with no parameters (but that's not what you need).